# formula for the checking of the PDE to be hyperbolic, elliptic, parabolic?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$Au_{xx} + 2Bu_{xy} + Cu_{yy} + Du_x + Eu_y + F = 0$
the formula that my book uses to check for the conditions for the elliptic, hyperbolic and the parabolic equation is 
$$b^2-4ac\gt 0$$ 
for hyperbolic equations,
$$b^2-4ac\lt 0$$
for elliptic equations and 
$$b^2-4ac=0$$ 
for the parabolic equation.
But on wiki it is mentioned to be by using 
$$b^2-ac,$$ 
is the result given in my book is wrong.
What is the soul derivation of saying about these equations to be hyperbolic, parabolic, elliptic?

Comment: Maybe that in your book the initial formula have a $B$ and not a $2B$ at the second term?

Comment: suppose i have a equation $u_{xx} + 2u_{xy} + u_{yy} = 0$ then to to find out which type of equation it is i can use $2^2-4=0$ @emilio novati

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition in  Wikipedia is correct and it is reffer to an equation written in the form:
$$Au_{xx} + 2Bu_{xy} + Cu_{yy} + Du_x + Eu_y + F = 0$$
, but I suspect that also the definition in you book is correct and it is referred to an equation written in the form:
$$Au_{xx} + B'u_{xy} + Cu_{yy} + Du_x + Eu_y + F = 0$$

Note that, in this case, we have:
$$
(B')^2-4AC=(2B)^2-4AC=4(B^2-AC)
$$